# SQL Injection: Drop All Tables

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, sql-injection, vulnerability-scanners, mysql

I used some vulnerability scanners to check a site of mine, and an instance of blind SQL injection was returned. However, when I try to exploit this vulnerability by entering the following into the address bar, nothing happens:

```
http://www.example.com/articles.php?id=-1' or 68 = '66; DROP ALL TABLES; --
```

I don't see why this isn't working. What is the correct text I must enter into the address bar to drop all the tables (and yes, I am testing this on a backup copy of the site)?

Comment: PHP and MySQL? What [API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) do you use?

Comment: @Gumbo, sorry, yes PHP and MySQL with mysqli.

Comment: Well, in case you use `mysqli_query`, you’re probably not allowed to execute [multiple statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) at once. You would need `mysqli_multi_query` instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **vast majority** of web applications do not allow query stacking. With PHP/MySQL application can allow for query stacking if you use the `mysqli::multi_query()`or `mysqli_multi_query()` functions.

You can exploit these systems using sub-select,  union-selects, blind sql injection,  `into outfile`, or  `loadfile()`.  SQLMap and Havij are both tools that automate the exploitation of SQL Injection. SQLMap is a great tool with a wide range of features, and supports a wide verity of injections and DBMS'es.

Comment: I'm also rather fond of the tool 'Havij' which is quite simply 'Aim and Fire' in most cases

Answer (score 0):

If the site does not use apostrophes (`'`) you can try this:

```
http://www.example.com/articles.php?id=-1; DROP ALL TABLES; --
```

Comment: It is still not working. It just displays the page as is.

Comment: Query stacking doesn't work in the real world, only in comic books and MS-SQL.