# SQL injection: insert data from Get request

Tags: sql-injection

I am using the vulnerable web app [mutillidae](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mutillidae/).

There is a webpage where you can view information from a profile but you first need to provide a user and a password. Once you click send, it sends it to a mysql database with this URL:

```
http//192.168.x.x/mutillidae/index.php
 ?page=user-info.php&username=the_userd&password=the_pass&user-info-php-submit-button=View+Account+Details
```

I know the table is `accounts` and the columns are: `cid, username, password, mysignature, is_admin`.

This screenshot shows the table accounts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuNyb.jpg

**I wish to be able to add a new user to the database (table accounts)**

I tried with these URLs:

```
http//192.168.x.x/mutillidae/index.php
 ?page=user-info.php&username=d"union insert into accounts ("cid","username","password","mysignature","is_admin") values ("18","bob1", "bob1","mysign","FALSE");--&password=d&user-info-php-submit-button=View+Account+Details 

http//192.168.x.x/mutillidae/index.php
 ?page=user-info.php&username=d";insert into accounts ("cid","username","password","mysignature","is_admin") values (18,"bob1", "bob1","mysign",FALSE);--&password=d&user-info-php-submit-button=View+Account+Details
```

If it can help, here is the pastebin of the vulnerable page (php source code): http://pastebin.com/wfnL68jw
with a sample:

```
            //Accept data from either GET or POST to make this target soft for SQLMAP
            $lUsername = $_REQUEST["username"];
            $lPassword = $_REQUEST["password"];

            $LogHandler->writeToLog($conn, "Recieved request to display user information for: " . $lUsername);

            $lQuery  = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='".
            $lUsername .
            "' AND password='" .
            $lPassword .
            "'";
            $lEncodeOutput = FALSE;
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @schroeder updated the question, I wish to add a new user to the database. (with insert if possible)

Comment: If you are sure this script is vulnerable: You might need to fiddle a bit with the encoding of your injection string. Does your HTTP client maybe auto-encode them differently that what you except them to be? Could you include the relevant part of the code of the service in your question so it is self containing and can be helpful for others, later on? This would also help make it easier for us to see what is happening.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser   I am sure it is vulnerable (it's meant to be and I was able to use the union select statement). I updated a link with the code of the page in the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Have you tried printing the resulting query? It should at least show you that you’re actually not injecting any additional SQL fragments.

Comment: Have a look at URLencoding and add after you insert query another select query for the password part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you would like to figure out the exact method yourself and are only looking to be pointed in the right direction.

PHP database query methods typically only allow a single query per call. So you have to make an injection that is part of the one query that is executed.

However, I'm pretty sure you can't INSERT data using injection, only manipulate the outcome of a SELECT.

Comment: if it is a login page (thus using INSERT), couldn't I craft an INSERT query to make a new account (admin)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can not create a nested insert. You could however, manipulate the original INSERT statement.

Comment: You seems right, even in this answer, he is saying the same thing https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33900/sql-injection-drop-all-tables. Although, UNION allow you to create a new request that is executed. What about that? it says here that UNION only allow SELECT http://www.sqlinjection.net/stacked-queries/